# VBA: how to hide rows if a cell contains a certain text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013. I am new to VBA. I found a code that would simply hide 2 rows (36 and 37) if my cell N39 is equal to "Passed"

I found that code but I receive the message "ambiguous name detected "Worksheet_Change"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("N39").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("N39").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

so I tried the name of my worksheet but it does nothing

```
Private Sub NRF(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("N39").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("N39").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Could it be because I have another code above?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim celltxt As String
    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("E39").Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "P670-Staffing") Then
    MsgBox "Add the job title and type of hire in the description cell - column H" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If this is a new position, please obtain your HRBP's approval"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has a typo "ows" instead of "Rows" in his code. Question is therefore unlikely to be useful for future readers.

Comment: I corrected the typo and still have the same error message

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name and parameters `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: I removed the previous code and it works. How could it make it work with the other code?

Comment: There is nothing calling `NRF`. `Worksheet_Change` is an event function that is called by Excel when the worksheet changes. You need to put **all of the code** inside `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: "I found that VBA code online" - you need to take some some time to learn Excel. Then you will 1/ understand what the code is doing and 2/ Understand the answer we give you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, aswer and advice to a blond girl! It worked. Yes, I plan to take some classes. A question of priorities

Answer (score 1):

#### Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

> I found that code but I receive the message "ambiguous name detected "Worksheet_Change"

You can't have two functions with the same name and parameters `Worksheet_Change`.

> I removed the previous code and it works. How could it make it work with the other code?

You need to put all of the code inside a single `Worksheet_Change` function.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my machine (Windows 7 x64, Excel 2016):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("N39").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("N39").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("36:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I think the misspelling of "Rows" as "ows" may have something to do with it. And I also had to remove the extraneous linefeed to get it to work.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but still have the same error message. I thought it could be the code I had prior but even if I delete the prior code, it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have this code attached to the sheet or as a separate module? It should be attached to the sheet.